# Why does DGV cause uncaught exception when removing item from DataSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a WinForms application with a DataGridView that has its DataSource property set to a BindingSource (which in turn has *its* DataSource set to a BindingList).

Everything works just fine, until I come to remove items from the BindingSource in response to a user request, the code I use for this is:

```
try
{
    // Get the item currently selected by the DGV
    var fc = (FooType)FooBindingSource.Current;
    // Remove the item from the binding source
    FooBindingSource.Remove(fch);
}
catch (Exception fault)
{
    MessageBox.Show(fault.Message);
}
```

The `Remove()` causes an exception. However in does not seem to be raised directly in the line of execution from this code as the `cathc` here does not catch the exception. Instead, when I run the application and test this functionality I see the DGV default error dialog several times. Suprisingly though, the end result is still that the item does get correctly deleted!

I can solve this by un-binding the BindingSource from the DGV before the `Remove()` (using `FooDataGridView.DataSource = null`) and rebinding it afterwards. But this feels... hacky, like I am just skirting round the issue rather than fixing it because I don't understand what is happening to cause the issue.

I believe that some event is happening while the item is removed, like the grid is getting validated or something.

What is causing this and is there a better way of preventing the exception?

The error dialogs I see contain the following information, all are titled "DataGridView Default Error Dialog"

First:

> The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
>
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 413 does not have a value.
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 rowIndex)
>
> To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

Second:

> The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
>
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 413 does not have a value.
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 boundColumnIndex, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
>
> To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

Third:

> The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
>
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 413 does not have a value.
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 rowIndex)
>
> To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

P.s: Just writing a quick DataError event handler know to look into this more but thought I'd get a head start here.

Comment: Did you try _FooBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();_ followed by a  _FooBindingSource.EndEdit();_ ?

Comment: @Steve No difference there I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the DGV DataError event, I can see that the event args Context property is set to "Display" for all three of the events. MSDN documents the meaning of display as

> A data error occurred when displaying a cell that was populated by a data source. This value indicates that the value from the data source cannot be displayed by the cell, or a mapping that translates the value from the data source to the cell is missing.

Thus I think this may have something to do with the DGV attempting to keep the removed row selected when it updates itself during the removal. Seeing as I have other TextBox controls displaying the same data also based on the selection then this looks like a possible thorny sort of circular validating event stack...

To test this I tried programmatically changing the selected row to something else immediately before removing the item - which worked! I could use this method but then what row should I have the code select when a user removes the last item? More thorns and spaghetti... So with at least a little understanding of what might be happening I'm OK now with using the unbinding and rebinding method I mentioned.