# Task.WaitAll() in DataGridView.RowEnter event causes DataError

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, task

I am using Advanced DataGridView (https://github.com/davidegironi/advanceddatagridview) to display some data in my application.

Within the RowEnter event I create tasks like this:

```
Dim One As String = dgv.Item("Col1", e.RowIndex)
Dim Two As String = dgv.Item("Col2", e.RowIndex)
Dim Three As String = dgv.Item("Col3", e.RowIndex)

Dim tOne As Task(Of DataTable) = Task.Run(Function() Return GetData(One) End Function)
Dim tTwo As Task(Of DataTable) = Task.Run(Function() Return GetData(Two) End Function)
Dim tThree As Task(Of DataTable) = Task.Run(Function() Return GetData(Three) End Function)

Task.WaitAll(tOne, tTwo, tThree)

'Do stuff with the results of tasks to update other labels etc on the form
lblDate.Text = tOne.Result.Rows(0).Item("Date").ToString
```

The reason for this is that if the `GetData()` function takes, say, 5 seconds to return doing this without tasks would result in a 15 second wait (5+5+5) whereas with tasks it only takes 5 seconds (or whatever the slowest task is) and Task.WaitAll gives control back to UI (unsure on correct terminology) so it feels a bit snappier.

However when I apply a filter I get the following exception repeatedly, where `[n]` is any number, I've seen indexes of -1 upwards (seems to depend on the number of visible rows?):

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index [n] does not have a value.
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 boundColumnIndex, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
```

If I remove the Task.WaitAll() or do the functions synchronously I don't get the above error.

I'm completely at a loss as to what the underlying cause of that error is, or what I should do different to avoid it.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504584/why-does-dgv-cause-uncaught-exception-when-removing-item-from-datasource) but I'm not sure how to apply to my situation.

Comment: How do the `DataTables` you're working with relate to any `DataGridView` controls?  I'm guessing that you're doing something to a `DataTable` that is bound to a `DataGridView` but it's not on the UI thread.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494147/windows-form-application-exception

Comment: @jmcilhinney Almost not at all... I use values from the current row to set a variable and use that variable in my tasks, then update some labels on the form with additional data from the tasks result. I've updated the question with additional code. All of the tasks/functions return a `New DataTable` or another type, they don't update any existing `DataTable`.

Comment: Use async event handler and await using `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: Using Task.WaitAll() on the UI thread is a very bad idea.  Basic problem is that it doesn't actually block the UI thread.  That's illegal, the CLR keeps dispatching messages.  The DoEvents-style re-entrancy bugs that can cause are very hard to diagnose.  Instead use Task.ContinueWith, using the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() scheduler.  You also have to fret about what happens when the user closes the window before the tasks are done.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Hans. That makes sense. With regards to `Task.ContinueWith()`, how does this apply to my situation, and does it have any benefits over Await Task.WhenAll() as suggested by Nkosi? The documentation  suggests `Task.ContinueWith()` is for doing branching logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async event handler and await the tasks using `Task.WhenAll`

```
' Mark the event handler with Async so you can use Await in it.
Private Async Sub Grid_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As WhateverEventArgs)
    Dim One As String = dgv.Item("Col1", e.RowIndex)
    Dim Two As String = dgv.Item("Col2", e.RowIndex)
    Dim Three As String = dgv.Item("Col3", e.RowIndex)

    Dim tOne As Task(Of DataTable) = Task.Run(Function() Return GetData(One) End Function)
    Dim tTwo As Task(Of DataTable) = Task.Run(Function() Return GetData(Two) End Function)
    Dim tThree As Task(Of DataTable) = Task.Run(Function() Return GetData(Three) End Function)

    ' await all the tasks
    Await Task.WhenAll(tOne, tTwo, tThree)

    ' back on UI thread

    'Do stuff with the results of tasks to update other labels etc on the form
    lblDate.Text = tOne.Result.Rows(0).Item("Date").ToString

End Sub
```

#### Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Nkosi. I've just been trying this from your comment and it seems to be working now. I'll have a read of that reference, although I think I've read it before... Really struggle to get my head around async, particularly because I'm working on some legacy code which is mostly synchronous!